# Follow the line length guidelines with long strings without including any extra blanks or newlines?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write a one-line long string in Python but I would like to follow the line length guidelines by showing it in multiple lines in the editor.

Problem Example:

```
long_string = "This is a very long string. Since it is a one-line string, I really want to keep it without any new line. However, I don't like how it looks in my code and it is annoying me"
```

I would like to achieve something similar to this (more readable and tidy):

```
long_string = "This is a very long string. Since it is a one-line string, I really want \
               to keep it without any new line. However, I don't like how it looks in my \
               code and it is annoying me"
```

However, the output adds spaces and/or newlines:

```
This is a very long string. Since it is a one-line string, I really want                to keep it without any new line. However, I don't like how it looks in my                code and it is annoying me
```

Although I know that there are ways to achieve it (as the following examples), in my opinion, these ways are not so easy to maintain:

```
long_string = "".join(["This is a very long string."],
                      ["Since it is a one-line string, I really want"],
                      ["to keep it without any new line. However, I don't like how"],
                      ["it looks in my code and it is annoying me"])
```

or

```
long_string = ("This is a very long string."
               "Since it is a one-line string, I really want"
               "to keep it without any new line. However, I don't like how"
               " ...")
```

Does anyone know an easier way to tackle this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: There are triple-quoted strings, spaning multiple lines: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: What's wrong with your very last example? This would be the easiest way to split a string across multiple lines.

Comment: You're absolutely right @ mkrieger1, I'm probably just a bit lazy having to double quote each line over and over again when some change to the text is required. So I was wondering if there was any other alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that requires neither repeated quotes, nor backslash line terminators (both of which impede editing the text because those characters have to be moved around) is to use a triple-quoted string and then strip newlines.

```
long_string = """
This is a very long string. Since it is a one-line string, I really want to
 keep it without any new line. However, I don't like how it looks in my code
 and it is annoying me
""".replace('\n', '')
```

This works as-is when in module scope and flush left. In an indented block it's also possible within stdlib:

```
from textwrap import dedent


def foo():
    long_string = dedent("""
    This is a very long string. Since it is a one-line string, I really want
     to keep it without any new line. However, I don't like how it looks in
     my code and it is annoying me
    """).replace('\n', '')
    print(long_string)


foo()
```

Comment: Great! Thanks @Jason S , that's exactly what I was looking for.